# How to get urls HTTP status code 403 with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-status-code-403

i have following javascript code, i want to get HTTP 403 Forbidden response code by using javascript, i tried following code and modified it, but its not working for me..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
request.open('GET', 'https://domain.com/file', true);
request.send();
request.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if (request.status === 403) {  
            alert("Oh no, it does not exist!");
        }
};



</script>
```

Comment: Forbidden (403) <> Not Found (404)

Comment: personally, I'd put the request.send() **AFTER** setting the onreadystatechange - well, if it were me i would use onload/onerror instead of onreadystatechange, but then, I don't CARE about pre IE9 browsers :p

Comment: yes, i also try it, but it return nothing

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try adding the `readyState` check, like so:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
request.open('GET', 'https://domain.com/file', true);
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
        if (request.status === 403) {  
            alert("Oh no, it does not exist!");
        }
    }
};
request.send();
```

Does this fix it?

Comment: No, i tested in firebug, url status is: "403 Forbidden" but javascript not detect this response.

Comment: Ah, I've just updated my answer. Could you stick the send() method on the end, after you've set up the readystatechange callback. Let me know what happens...

Comment: i tried this code with 404, 403, i put in header and then in body contents, but it return nothing..

Comment: I'm sorry @Ahmediqbal, I'm a little stumped on this one. It's working OK for me. In this example, I have configured a mock API to return a 403, and I get the alert message, no problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kieranpotts/skgcp1u6/

Comment: first send request then check status

Comment: yesh, i put request.send(); in end of  javascript code, but its not working

Comment: @K.P. you can try this url: //technobb.com/test.php

Comment: So, I know the final answer now! Although the technobb.com server is indeed returning a 403, it does NOT include an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in its response, which is required to allow cross-origin requests (CORS). You will need to enable CORS on the technobb.com server in order to be able to make requests to it via Ajax. There's plenty of information out there on CORS, just search StackOverflow or Google.  Good luck! http://jsfiddle.net/kieranpotts/skgcp1u6/1/

Comment: This url 403 return '0B' in size, can i count url size with javascript ?